# In PStricks, what is the difference between \psforeach and \multido in the following?

Tags: pstricks, multido

My code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,newcent}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{multido}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-.5,-1.5)(6.5,1.5)
\psforeach{\m}{.5,1.5,2.5,3.5,4.5,5.5}{\psline(0,\m)(\m,0)}
\end{pspicture}

\begin{pspicture}(-.5,-1.5)(6.5,1.5)
\multido{\n=0.5+1}{6}{\psline(0,\n)(\n,0)}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

The result compiling:

[image]

Question:

These commands are equivalent !?. Why are there differences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for *equidistant values* it makes no difference. But `\multido` cannot work with something like `1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, ...` and, of course, `\multido` uses some predefined macros:

```
\i   for integers
\n   for natural numbers
\r   for real
```

In your example it should be

```
\multido{\r=0.5+1}{6}{\psline[linecolor=red](0,\r)(\r,0)}
```

Comment: In above question, \multido{\n=0.5+1}{6}, it has also equidistant values. So, can you explain more clearly?

Comment: see edited answer

Comment: for `multido` everything is declared in the documentation. For `psforeach` you can use any macro you like and which is not already defined.

Comment: please answer the above question!

Comment: @chishimotoji you can use for example \multido{\ri=0.5+1}{6}{\psline(0,\ri)(\ri,0)}  or  \multido{\ra=0.5+1}{6}{\psline(0,\ra)(\ra,0)}

Comment: @Thomas Why can we use \ri and \ra for example. They are not defined in multido's documentation.

Comment: everything which starts with `\r` is for real numbers